# How to removing JSON Array parent and keep the child json array

Tags: javascript, json

I know there's so much question about removing specific `JSON`, but when I try to search any specific question to remove JSON array like I have, I'm not yet find it, so I'll ask here:

I have a json like this getting from `SQL Server Store Procedure` :

```
[
    {
        "KODE": [
            {
                "name": "kode",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "value": "DIAG001",
                        "RankNum": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "DIAG002",
                        "RankNum": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "DIAG003",
                        "RankNum": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "DIAG004",
                        "RankNum": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "HEALING": [
            {
                "name": "Encountrance",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG001",
                        "Name": "Subsequent"
                    },
                    {
                        "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG002",
                        "Name": "Initial"
                    },
                    {
                        "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG003",
                        "Name": "Initial"
                    },
                    {
                        "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG004",
                        "Name": "Subsequent"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to remove `parent JSON array` of `KODE, HEALING`, so my json gonna look's like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "kode",
        "value": [
            {
                "value": "DIAG001",
                "RankNum": 1
            },
            {
                "value": "DIAG002",
                "RankNum": 1
            },
            {
                "value": "DIAG003",
                "RankNum": 1
            },
            {
                "value": "DIAG004",
                "RankNum": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Encountrance",
        "value": [
            {
                "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG001",
                "Name": "Subsequent"
            },
            {
                "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG002",
                "Name": "Initial"
            },
            {
                "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG003",
                "Name": "Initial"
            },
            {
                "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG004",
                "Name": "Subsequent"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

anyone can help me how to do that programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the array and use the values of the object for a concat.

```js
var data = [{ KODE: [{ name: "kode", value: [{ value: "DIAG001", RankNum: 1 }, { value: "DIAG002", RankNum: 1 }, { value: "DIAG003", RankNum: 1 }, { value: "DIAG004", RankNum: 1 }] }], HEALING: [{ name: "Encountrance", value: [{ Diagnosis_Code: "DIAG001", Name: "Subsequent" }, { Diagnosis_Code: "DIAG002", Name: "Initial" }, { Diagnosis_Code: "DIAG003", Name: "Initial" }, { Diagnosis_Code: "DIAG004", Name: "Subsequent" }] }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(...Object.values(o)), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks sir, because I'm not familiar about Javascript, can you tell me what's the function of three dots at `...Object.values`? does it like `push`?

Comment: it's [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which takes an iterable object and use the parts as parameters for the function.